# setter function is being invoked seemingly every render but its not causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const YTPlayer = ({playlist}) => {
      const [player,setPlayer] = useState(false)
      const loadPlaylist = playlist => {
        player.loadPlaylist(playlist);
      };
      const play = () => {
        loadPlaylist(playlist);
        player.playVideo();
      };
      const pause = () => {
        player.pauseVideo();
      };

      const onReady = event => setPlayer(event.target)
      return <YoutubeIFrame onReady={onReady} /> 
}
```

The YouTube Iframe calls the onReady argument once it has loaded, which calls setPlayer. So YTPlayer should rerender, destroying the previous Iframe and creating a new one that also does the same thing. Shouldn't this cause an infinite loop?

Thats what I expected, but it doesn't behave that way. It rerenders 5 times, then stops. The play,pause,loadPlaylists functions all work fine. So What is the mistake in my thinking?

Comment: Nothing rendered in the application depends on the `player` state. Since there's nothing to change when the state changes, there is no re-render of the application. Try rendering something that uses `player` and see that it causes the infinite loop you expected.

Comment: I did't include my full code for brevity, but I do have multiple functions using player. Such as:


const play = () => {
    loadPlaylist(playlist);
    player.playVideo();
  };

Comment: Again, you don't **render** anything that uses `player`. Also, your `player` state is a boolean, but you call the methods `playVideo` and `pauseVideo` on it? It seems that your new example is missing some things.